# How to change attribute values of included layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with `RelativeLayout` as parent and a child `TextView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <TextView
     android:text="Test Include"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This layout is included into another `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <include layout="@layout/include_me"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Issue:** I am trying to change the attribute values of the included layout. But `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` or `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` doesn't make any effect.

**Does that changing the attribute values in include has no effect?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding also `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to the `<include` tag

Comment: It worked.Thanks. Does `include` tag has its own default `attributes` `values`? I was in an understanding that it should take the included layout attribute values.